# Vue.js 2 + Typescript - global variables becomes undefined after build

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have a Vue.js 2 project with Typescript. In the `main.ts` file, I've declared 2 variables, that I've wanted to access globally in my project:

```
// ...
Vue.prototype.$http = http; // this is the library imported from another file, contains various methods such as `get`, `post` etc.
Vue.prototype.$urls = urls; // this is JSON object, also imported from another file
new Vue({
  store,
  render: (h) => h(App),
}).$mount('#app');
```

In one of my components, let's call it `User` I have following `mounted` code block:

```
mounted(): void {
  this.$http.get(`${this.$urls.getUser}/${this.userId}`);
}
```

Everything works fine when I'm running a local server (via `npm run serve` command), but when I create an app build (via `npm run build` command) and enter the app on the server (or the `index.html` file on my hdd) I receive following error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined
    at VueComponent.value (user.ts:62)  // <-- this line is the one with $http.get from `mounted` hook
```

I'm not sure how to proceed with this, I've blindly tried to add those global values to various places e.g. in `http.d.ts` file I have the following:

```
import { KeyableInterface } from '@/interfaces/HelperInterfaces';
import Vue from 'vue';

declare module 'vue/types/vue' {
  interface VueConstructor  {
    $http: KeyableInterface;
  }
}

declare module 'vue/types/vue' {
  interface Vue  {
    $http: KeyableInterface;
  }
}

declare module 'vue/types/options' {
  interface ComponentOptions<V extends Vue> {
    http?: KeyableInterface
  }
}
```

(I've also created `urls.d.ts` with similar code)

UPDATE #1:

I've tried also following approach - in my `main.ts` file:

```
const helperModules = {
  /* eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any */
  install: (vueInstance: any) => {
    vueInstance.prototype.$http = http;
    vueInstance.prototype.$urls = urls;
  },
};

Vue.use(helperModules);
```

But it still doesn't work (same error).

UPDATE #2:

I've also imported `http` utility into my `user` component, and added following `console.log` to existing `mounted` callback:

```
console.log(http, this.$http)
```

And while working on my `localhost`, it returns me twice the same value, but when I create a build it returns me:

```
Module {__esModule: true, Symbol(Symbol.toStringTag): "Module"}, undefined
```

Similar thing happens, when I add `console.log(urls, this.$urls)` - imported module is being logged, while prototyped one returns `undefined`.

Any thoughts? Will appreciate any help.

Comment: are you creating your component using `Vue.extend`?

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim what do you mean exactly? (I'm not 100% sure but I assume that I don't use `Vue.extend` there). I'm creating a Vue.js SPA, where I would like to use global variables across all components inside it. I did it in the past, but this is my first TypeScript project and I see the guide from documentation doesn't work in this case after build.

Comment: [`Vue.extend`](https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-extend) is needed to get the types infered when you use TS, but I recommend to try to use vue 3 which supports TS very well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I've overcome the problem by moving the prototyping parts from `main.ts` to `App.ts` file.

I'm not 100% sure if it's a valid "the Vue.js way" of solving this, as I've always declared that in `main.js` file - but I was using then JavaScript & it was "just working" as expected.